# Populate second input text based on previous one

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm building a form where I would like to insert in some text input, a number, and in the next input text, auto populate with the name that matches the number in the DB. I've tested many "solutions" which I saw here and on other sites but none worked.

**My script code is:**

```
$("#numero").blur(function () {
    $.post(convoc.php, { numero: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
        $("#nome").val(data);
    });
});
```

**My convoc.php code:**

```
if (@$_POST['numero'] != "")
        $numero = $_POST['numero'];
$query  = "SELECT Nome from ******* where Numero = $numero";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    echo json_encode($row['Nome']);
```

*(This is working well, because I've tested the echo and it's printing the correct name)*

The id of my first input text is: "numero" and the id of the second input is "nome".

Is there something I'm doing wrong in the script function?

The HTML code is:

```
<body onload="load()" style="padding-top: 20px;">
    <form action="convoc.php" method="post">
        <div id="myform">
        <table align="center">
<tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="numero" name="numero"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="nome" name="nome"></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="add" value="Convocar" onclick="Javascript:addRow()"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</div>

</form>
</body>
```

The js code is:

```
function addRow() {

    var numero = document.getElementById("numero");
    var nome = document.getElementById("nome");
    var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");


    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= '<input type="button" value = "Delete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">';
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= numero.value;
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= nome.value;
}

function deleteRow(obj) {

    var index = obj.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
    table.deleteRow(index);

}

function load() {

    console.log("Page load finished");

}
```

(And no, i'm not receiving any error in the browser)

Comment: Show us the HTML please.

Comment: Show your HTML code..

Comment: Is the load() function defined? Can you please post the response from the ajax call? Are you getting any error in the console of your browser?

Comment: Is element with id "numero", added dynamically? What version of jQuery are you using? Debugging in your console area might be helpful.

Comment: Nishant, I insert the element with id "numero" manually. And the version of jQuery is the 1.6.2

Answer (score 2):

Change the script code as below.

> The first parameter `convoc.php` should be `'convoc.php'`.

```
$(function(){
    $("#numero").blur(function () {
        //use $.ajax
    $.ajax({
        url:'convoc.php',
        dataType:'json', //The datatype should be json because you are returning in json format
        data : {numero: $(this).val()},
        success:function(data){
        $("#nome").val(data.result);
        }
    });
    });
});
```

Also change the php code as below.

```
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$row['Nome']));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still does not work. I'm going crazy with this, and i bet it's a stupid little thing in the code that's missing...

Comment: Once again appreciate the answer, but continues not working.

Comment: I don't know why, but it's not working. The convoc.php is sending the correct result because i've checked it again and it sended this: {"result":"Manuel Fernandes Martins"}
The problem need to be in the blur event, but don't know why. I guess i'll quit and try to make this in a different way. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I do not see an id on your table tag

Comment: Fintan Creaven, and it's suposed to have one? The blur(function) does not only need the id of the fields?

Answer (score 0):

**Just Add Json On end:**

```
$("#numero").blur(function () {
   $.post(convoc.php, { numero: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
     $("#nome").val(data);
  });
},"json");  // This Line
```